# cx_Oracle giving ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges Logging in as SYSDBA

Tags: python, sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect Oracle remote database server using Python cx_Oracle. In sqlplus I do use "**sqlplus / as sysdba**" for connecting server using putty Console and i am to login successfully.  Can you please help me on this why it was throwing this error.

```
import cx_Oracle
tns= cx_Oracle.makedsn('ip', port, SERVICE NAME = 'SID')   
db = cx_Oracle.connect('SYS', 'password', tns, mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
```

It was throwing Error :

```
cx_Oracle Database Error ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I already made one normal DB user and tried connecting with and it was Successful.

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('USERNAME', 'password', tns)
```

Comment: Could you try cx_Oracle.connect("sys/password@sid", mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)?

Comment: I'd suggest you **not** to use SYS nor SYSTEM. They *own* the database and should be used only for administrative tasks no other user can perform. I, somehow, doubt that your Python script will do that. Therefore, use another user you created.

Comment: VN'sCorner yes I tried cx_Oracle.connect("sys/password@sid", mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA) and even this cx_Oracle.connect("sys/password@sid", tns,mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA) But it was throwing Type Error Expecting string or byte Object Error.

Comment: LittleFoot Yes id understood But i need this to perform some DBA tasks Like Adding Dbf Files and some other DB  tasks in My Application .

Comment: Run SQL\*Plus on the computer where you run Python.  Get that connection syntax working first, then try in Python.  And follow everyone else's advice.  Try `sqlplus -l "sys/mypassword@myhost.example.com/orclpdb1 as sysdba"`  With SQL*Plus 19 you can omit the password on the command line and you will be prompted for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do most (all?) of the kind of things you mentioned with the normal "DBA" role. SYSDBA is often only necessary when doing things that require restart of the database, software and patch installation, or with backup/recovery scenarios, and is insanely overpowered for day-to-day uses. Depending on your version of Oracle, it is capable of bypassing many security features entirely, and is generally not safe to use within most scripts and applications for that reason. Use should be limited to things that *only* SYSDBA can do.

Additionally, the SYS user may not be allowed to connect over the network (you're using a TNS connection), as it is authenticated by the server operating system which implies local login only. That's why "sqlplus / as sysdba" works when you're logged in to the database server.

Consider the following:

1. If you *must* have actual SYSDBA privileges and nothing else will do, grant the SYSDBA role to another user and use that instead. As @Littlefoot suggested, *never* use the SYS or SYSTEM accounts for day-to-day administrative work, either on the server or remotely.
2. Never embed username and password in your scripts or application code, *especially* for an account that powerful. Use an Oracle Wallet to hold encrypted user credentials instead, or better yet prompt the user to enter them at runtime. Putting credentials like that directly in a script is a sure way to fail a security audit.
3. Follow the principle of least privilege and don't use a SYSDBA or DBA-role enabled account for anything else other than what you need those specific privileges to do (adding files, etc.). Use lesser accounts where possible.
4. When using privileged accounts like those with DBA or SYSDBA privileges over the network, you should encrypt all communications.

See these links for details:

- https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2020/01/13/how-to-hide-oracle-passwords-in-a-script/
- https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2014/10/16/database-account-password-storage/